# No diskspace on AWS Image?

Tags: ubuntu, mount, aws

we are currently testing AWS, therefore I created an EC2 instance using a bitnami-magento image. The AWS intance has 10gb of space attached to it. Now all of a sudden, I am out of diskspace and I have no clue how.

Output of df -h:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      9.8G  9.3G     0 100% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            1.9G   12K  1.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           375M  196K  375M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
```

Output of lsblk:

```
NAME  MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda1 202:1    0  10G  0 disk /
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you see from the output you've posted, almost all of the space used is allocated to `/`, the top-level (or "root", but not to be confused with the `root` user) filesystem. In fact, on your system that's the *only* real mounted filesystem. And, you can see that that's 100% used.

```
/dev/xvda1      9.8G  9.3G     0 100% /
```

The next thing to do is to drill down on that filesystem and find which subdirectories are taking up the space. Try:

```
cd /
sudo du -sh * 2>/dev/null | sort -h
```

Which will tell which of the subdirecctories of / are biggest, with the largest at the bottom.

```
0   /bin
0   /lib
0   /lib64
0   /proc
0   /sbin
0   /sys
4.0K    /media
4.0K    /mnt
4.0K    /sysroot
16K /lost+found
156K    /root
496K    /opt
1.3M    /run
2.0M    /tmp
2.7M    /dev
41M /etc
125M    /boot
8.9G    /usr
14G /var
17G /srv
21G /home
```

Here, most of *my* stuff is in `/home`. That might be the case on yours, although my bet as a sysadmin is that something on `/var`. Next step,

```
cd /var  # or whatever seems abnormally large
sudo du -sh * 2>/dev/null | sort -h
```

and look to see if any log files or temporary data or anything else has gotten out of control.

Comment: Thanks. I have found the largest directories: the magento install takes up 7.2gb and most of that is product images which for obvious reasons I can not delete. Does this simply mean I litterally ran out of space and just have to extend the volume?! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @blackcud Yes, sounds like it.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to check system logs. go to directory /var/log and clear some old log files.
Next you can check the entire /var directory with command:

```
du -sh /var
```

to see which directory "eat" the diskpace